# ASP.NET MVC w/ EF: using Unity with the Repository Pattern for IoC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm trying to implement some kind of IoC on an ASP.NET MVC 3 project (built with Entity Framework for data access) by using Unity. Entities are being converted to custom objects that implement a common interface. Those custom objects are used by the controller who puts them in a "view model" and forward it to the view.

I'm following some guides but I can't find out how to configure Unity so that the right object is mapped for every controller.

Can someone point me to a good guide/tutorial/how-to? Hope I have clearly explained the problem...
I have never used Unity, so forgive me if that's a dumb/noobish question.

Thanks in advance,

Daniele Salatti

Comment: Do you just want to inject repository into your controller, or do you want more than that?

Comment: In general you shouldn't abstract away your domain layer (entities). Instead of implementing interfaces on your entities, make them POCOs. This prevents you from having to put an abstraction on top of them.

Comment: @Steven: going to read something about that... I don't know POCO.

Comment: Sorry, is the repository the only think you want to inject? Or do you want to inject you entites / domain model objects as well?

Comment: @Daniele: Just Google "Entity Framework POCO"

Comment: @zespri: I want to inject my entities too. Sorry, I didn't understand before...

Comment: Why do you want to inject entities, aren't they coming straight from you repository? And where are you wanting to inject them to?

Comment: That's the point, but maybe I misunderstood something. I want Unity to create those entities and inject them into my controllers. I'm new to Unity (first time I use it) and a noob in IoC so there's a chance (read: I'm almost sure) that I'm misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post it explain how to implement `Repository Pattern` for `EntityFrameWork`

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx